# C# - Starting process under different user than the IIS application pool user

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

```
        public static string StartProcess(string cmd, string args, string workingDirectory, string username, string password)
        {
        // launch system process
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd, args);
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UserName = username;
        startInfo.Password = ConvertStringToSecureString(password);

        // get working directory from executable path
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory))
        {
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(cmd);
        }
        else
        {
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        }
        var results = new StringBuilder();
        using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.Close();
            var reader = process.StandardOutput;
            string lineOut;
            while ((lineOut = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                results.AppendLine(lineOut);
            }
            while (!process.HasExited) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        return results.ToString();
        }
```

I am trying to launch a process from within my IIS application using a different username / password than the one that the IIS application pool is operating under.

The IIS app pool is running under a full admin user, and when the process starts, it completes, the result is return, no issues. When I specify a username / password, the process starts, then immediately closes.

I also have

```
Application popup: conhost.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.
```

in my event logs. If I take the above code and put into its own exe file and run it via the desktop using the same admin user IIS is running under, the process starts (using the username / password for the other user) and completes without issues.

It appears to just be limited to IIS. Am I missing something?

Comment: where do `cmd` and `args` come from? This looks like a severe direct object access vulnerability.

Comment: They are part of the method parameters.

cmd, args, workingDirectory, username, password are all passed in by the method's params.

Comment: Are you trying to execute an `.exe` file or some other thing such as `.bat`, `.ps1`?

Comment: Yes, but are these parameters supplied by the user? Do you validate that they do not try to run a destructive command?

Comment: I've only tried an .exe. Reason I only did .exe is because it works when I do not supply any specific credentials. It only fails when I set credentials. I have verified the credentials are correct. Like I said, it works outside of IIS, but not within IIS. No these are not supplied by a user, I supply command and arguments. However regardless who supplies them, has no outcome of my original question.

Comment: This executes php.exe (different versions) with a supplied parameter of the file that I'd like to execute with the PHP CLI.

    `StartProcess("php.exe", "-f phpfile.php", "C:\\php", "siteuser_iusr", "password");`

Answer (score -1):

For me chaging the user/process id of the application pool of my site worked.

Go to IIS Manager **->** app pools **->** select your pool **->** advanced settings
**->** under process model you can set your identity for example to your local admin account.